# pandas bool type to yes or no

Tags: pandas, pyexcelerate

I am dealing with nearly 100000 rows of data so I am using pyexcelerate to write excel file through the dataframe. When I was using `pd.ExcelWriter(path)` i was able to map a bool field of pandas to yes or no but now using pyexcelerate i get `#NUM!`  in the cell .
Also,pyexcelerate only writes 1/0 in the file for the bool field.

```
wb = Workbook()
df['abc'] = df['abc'].map({1:True,0:False})
values = [df.columns] + df.values.tolist()
wb.new_sheet('Data', data=values)
```

how can i map 1/0 to yes/no ?

Comment: try converting the column to `bool` if you have binary values and then use `np.where`: `np.where(df['abc'].astype(bool),'yes','no')` ?

Comment: didnt use numpy before. thanks . works for me.